# Function doesn't return value to main program (Visual Studio)

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to Visual Studio and I'm trying to create a menu for my coursework, however when I call the menu function it runs but it does not return the "UserChoice" back into the main program.

Module Coursework

```
Sub Main()

    Console.Title = "Coursework"

    Dim UserChoice As Integer


    Call Menu()

    If UserChoice = 1 Then
        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the accuracy option. 
        Please enter the number you want to round up:")

        Dim NumberToRound As Long
        NumberToRound = Console.ReadLine()


        Call Menu()    ' By putting "Call Menu()" at the end of each choice we make a loop until the user has chosen option 5 which closes the program.
    End If


End Sub


Function Menu()
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose an option:

    1. Accuracy
    2. Quadratic equation
    3. Protein Sequence Segmentation
    4. Monte-Carlo Integration of a function
    5. Close the program                       ")

    Dim UserChoice As Integer
    UserChoice = Console.ReadLine()
    Return UserChoice
End Function
```

Anyone has any ideas why that is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *but it does not return the "UserChoice" back* it does but you do nothing with it - that's what Call do - discards  returned value

Comment: Even without the `Call` keyword, you still have no other code in your `Main` method to make use of the value the method would return. What exactly do you expect to happen to that value?

Comment: You are often allowed to assume that valid input will be provided when doing homework for beginner classes but it's worth considering the fact that the user may not enter a number in the range 1-5 and may not enter a number at all. A real application would have to consider that. Assigning the `String` returned by `Console.ReadLine` to an `Integer` variable is not safe.

Comment: @jmcilhinney What do you mean I have no other code in my main? The value from the function is meant to be returned to the main program to be used in the if statement.

Comment: `call` **was** used to make porting programs written before 1984 to Visual Basic Ver 1. Function calls are slow, you are making 2 for every 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply ignoring what you obviously already know. Look at this from your own code:

```
Dim UserChoice As Integer
UserChoice = Console.ReadLine()
```

What does that do? It declares a variable, calls a method and assigns the result to the variable. Now look at this:

```
Dim UserChoice As Integer


Call Menu()
```

Do you see any difference there? You declaring a variable and calling a method but, for some reason, you think that the result of that method will magically appear in the variable for no discernible reason. If you expect a variable to have a value then you have to assign that value to it and you obviously know how to do that because you're doing it elsewhere. Why should it be different here?

```
Dim UserChoice As Integer

UserChoice = Menu()
```

Comment: I thought that by putting "UserChoice = Console.Readline()" in the function it will make it so when the function is finished I will be able to use the changed variable in sub main()

Comment: @Chromosomeh, I suggest that learn about scope. The fact that you declared two separate variables should have clued you in to that fact that setting one would have no effect on the other. The fact that they have the same name doesn't create a mystical connection between them. You could have named them anything. If you want to set a variable in one method and use it in another then it must be the same variable, declared outside both methods. If you did that though, what would be the point of the `Menu` method returning anything at all? If you want to use the return value then use it.

Comment: I thought it will be enough to just declare the variable in the function however every time I do so it says that I also need to declare it in the main, which is where the problem is. I'm new to vb so I'm still learning how it works.

Comment: If you declare a variable in a method then it only exists in that method, so you can't use it outside that method. Like I said, learn about scope. A thing only exists within the scope it is declared. If you have to make two declarations then that should be a clue that you have two different variables.